# Why does bootstrap input that displays elsewhere disappear immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, input

I have a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/vr8cye5f/).

When I run the code, it starts up fine. I input the date and click to insert, and it appears for half a second, and then disappears completely.

The fiddle says `**{"error": "Please use POST request"}**`, but it's doing the same thing on my browser.

Any thoughts on this?

**HTML**

```
<h4>Insert Date Here</h4>
<form role="form">  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="input-group input-group-md">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"/>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button id="get" class="btn">Insert Date</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form> 

<p>
  Nisi odio purus mattis. Habitasse nunc enim cursus cum est aenean nisi, enim odio, ultricies, sit arcu platea, pid, turpis. Parturient, arcu sed tristique? Placerat, <span id='msg'></span> parturient, non ridiculus aenean porttitor mauris amet! Elementum in ridiculus, scelerisque proin, risus, turpis magna dignissim habitasse, dis sed, eros. Ut rhoncus sed, lectus tincidunt.
</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#get").click(function () {
    $('#msg').html($('input:text').val());

});
```

Comment: It's because you're submitting the form, and performing a get operation. How are you wanting to handle the form? Are you wanting it to submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your button is inside the form you need to prevent default:

```
$("#get").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#msg').html( $('input:text').val());           
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It dissapears, because you submit form. Add this, it will prevent form submition:

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Keammoort/cdatx20n/)